# Load Sqlanywhere data provider in powershell

Tags: powershell, sqlanywhere

In Powershell v5 I'm Trying to load the ianywhere provider dll.  I'm getting this loader exception:

```
Â : The term 'Â' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the
spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
```

Weird, right?
My load command is

```
Add-Type -path "C:\Temp\sa\iAnywhere.Data.SQLAnywhere.v4.0.dll"
```

The ianywhere dll requires accompanying native dlls, which I have placed in the same folder.  Those come in two versions, 32bit and 64 bit.  I've tried both, and I've tried 32bit powershell and 64bit powershell.  My shell is running as admin as well.

Comment: I think this is because of the ASCII encoding. Open with notepad++ and see how it is coming. You can change it then accordingly

Comment: ASCII encoding?  I think you misunderstand the issue.  I'm trying to load a DLL.

Comment: I got it. But I strongly believe its becuase of the Letter A in ianywhere which is giving the issue. Try opening in notepad++ and see the encoding type

Comment: Open what in notepad?  the dll?  you can't mean that.  And  there's no script to open: I just typed the add-type command.

Comment: I am talking about this line only. Just copy this line and put that in notepad++ not notepad. You will come to know the encoding type. Change it to utf8 and try once more